# Open page save dialog from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to trigger Chrome's own Save As (page context menu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) dialog from an extension? Or somehow sending this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> command to the active tab? My extension makes some modifications on the active tab then puts a new "Save whole page" button into the top of it. To avoid confusion, I do not want to programmatically save anything or writing to the disk. I do not need `chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML` or `chrome.downloads.download`. I just need to open the save as dialog by the click of my button instead of manually right click on the page and choosing "Save as". This would be a private extension only for my needs so any working solution would be fine.

I have `content_script` (content.js) and `background` (background.js):

```
// part of my background.js   
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === "adatlap_savehtml") {
        // open Save As dialog (CTRL+S) for savaing files (html, images) separately
    }
  }
);
```

and

```
// part of my content.js        
$btnSaveHtml.click(function() {
  // this could be useles if the Save As dialog can be opened here.. (?)
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "adatlap_savehtml"});
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, there's no API to invoke built-in commands.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! After googling a day I also haven't found anything but it's so unbelievable.. :(